# Using custom pipe and async pipe together

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In my project I have a custom pipe to filter a list:

```
@Pipe({name: 'filterList'})
export class FilterListPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string[], arg: string[]): any {
    if (!value) return value;
    return value.filter( el => !arg.includes(el));
  }
}
```

I'm using this pipe as follows:

```
<md-select placeholder="Grupos" (change)="changeGroup($event)">
  <md-option 
    *ngFor="let group of (allGroups | async) | filterList : (userDetail | async)?.groups" 
    [value]="group">
    {{ group }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

The problem is I receive an error raised in the FilterListPipe :

> arg is null

So this is not working:

```
let group of (allGroups | async) | filterList : (userDetail | async)?.groups
```

Can I somehow use the result of async to be passed as an argument of my custom pipe?
Or should I subscribe to the observable in my class and create another class variable?

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem:

I had to put my custom pipe before the async pipe. Like this:

```
*ngFor="let group of allGroups | filterList : (userDetail | async)?.groups | async"
```

and now the value of the first argument in tranform function is an observable, so:

```
@Pipe({name: 'filterList'})
export class FilterListPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: Observable<any>, arg: string[]): any {
        return value
            .map( groups => groups.filter( el=> !arg.includes(el) ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: using custom pipe before async means you are transforming a observable/promise before subscribed which is done by async pipe, passing async before custom pipe means first the observable is subscribed and you are using the pipe